# Find $\int _{[0,1]} f \, \, d \lambda$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $e_k(x)$ be the $k$-th digit after the decimal point $x$ written as a decimal. Let $f(x) = e_2(x)$ (so if $f(0.521)=2$)

Find $$\int _{[0,1]} f \, \, d \lambda$$

I have no idea how to do this. Please help.

Comment: What does the `\lambda` mean here?

Comment: Hint: Break $[0,1]$ into $100$ parts. Try to figure out the function value at each subintervals.

Comment: @JohnMa Would you please be able to show me this one because I just need to see how it is solved so I can do other ones...

Comment: The function is not well-defined ,e,g. $1/100=0.01=0.00\bar 9$, although there are a finite number $(100)$ of points where $f$ is not defined,so you can assign arbitrary values to $f$ at those points without affecting the integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have that $$\int_{[0,1]}fd\lambda=\int_{[0,0.1]}fd\lambda+\dots+\int_{[0.9,1]}fd\lambda.$$
Note that $f(x+0.1)=f(x)$ to get that
$$\int_{[0,1]}fd\lambda=10\times\int_{[0,0.1]}fd\lambda.$$
Now write
$$\int_{[0,0.1]}fd\lambda=\int_{[0,0.01]}fd\lambda+\dots+\int_{[0.09,0.1]}fd\lambda=0.01\times[1+\dots+9]$$ to finally get
$$\int_{[0,1]}fd\lambda=10\times 0.01\times45=4.5.$$

Comment: +1 Really slick! But is it clear that $f$ is measurable to begin with?

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan : Yes because you can write $$f=0\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0,0.01]\cup[0.1,0.11]\cup\dots}+1\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0.01,0.02]\cup[0.11,0.12]\cup\dots}+\dots,$$ and each of the sets are finite unions of intervals so borelians.